# Manejo de superposicion de ventas activas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ventana, python-3.8

Son un principiante de Python y estoy creando un app y tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

He creado un archivo principal llamado `index.py` donde tengo la ventana principal de la app con menús que llaman a otros archivos .py a ser ejecutados (subprogramas que ejecutan una ventana) y estos a su vez tienen alertas de `messagebox`. Al momento que se ejecuta el subprograma los mensaje me llevan a sobreponer la ventana inicial sobre las demás y no se mantiene al frente de la app la ventana del programa donde se genera el messagebox.

Ej:

`Index.py(Tk())`->`Menú`->`Opcion1`->`Tk(RegistroUser.py)` -> `messagebox` - Cuando se activa el messagebox lo hace sobre la ventana index.py y la ventana de RegistroUser.py se pone detrás

tanto el programa index.py y RegistroUser.py tiene la instrucción:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   window = Tk()
   application = Yams(window)
   window.mainloop()
```

¿Cómo puedo mantener la ventana del programa que esta activo en ese momento?

Gracias de antemano a quien me pueda orientar

Comment: Muchas gracias x la explicación. Como lo manejarías de acuerdo a la explicación de tener un archivo .py donde se encuetra el menú ppal de la aplicación y en cada opción del menú llama un archivo .py con la instrucción execfile('Archivo.py' ). en Archivo.py hago apertura de un Tk(), cambie Tk() x Toplevel() pero sucede igual.

Comment: Hola Juan, so comentas en tu propia publicación sin hacer mención al usuario con @ no se le notificará, no había visto antes el mensaje. No se que te impulsa a usar execfile, si tienes la app en varios módulos usa clases importa y compón la interfaz en el módulo principal, de ésta forma todo es más natural y simple, luego pasa referencias del padre alas ventans toplevel como debe ser y pasa el padre adecuado a a cada message.

Answer (score 0):

Para que el orden sea el correcto, ventana secundaria encima de principal y messagebox encima de Secundaria hay dos cosas que debes tener siempre presentes:

- Genera siempre tus ventanas secundarias usando `tkinter.TopLevel`, no generes más de una instancia de `tkinter.Tk`.
- Pasa siempre el padre a todo widget que crees, siempre, incluso a las variables (como `tkinter.StringVar`). En éste caso usa el argumento `parent` de los distintos sabores de messagebox.

Un ejemplo completo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Secundaria(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Button(
            self, text="Abrir Message",
            command=self.open_message).pack(expand=True)

    def open_message(self):
        messagebox.showinfo(
            "Test", "Hola soy un mensage de información", parent=self
            )


class Principal(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Button(
            self, text="Abrir Ventana Secundaria",
            command=self.open_child).pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    def open_child(self):
        sec = tk.Toplevel(self)
        sec.title("Secundaria")
        sec.geometry("650x400+450+350")
        Secundaria(sec).pack(fill="both", expand=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Principal")
    root.geometry("650x400+400+300")
    Principal(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Por facilidad ambas clases están en el mismo módulo, pero que estén en distintos es irrelevante, simplemente importar la clase, el resto es igual.